# Any event afterPop()? not ionViewDidLeave() in Ionic2

Tags: ionic2

Is there an event that fires `afterPop()` in Ionic2? Because in my case the `ionViewWiillLeave` does not serve me.

I have a `Page1` that pushes `Page2` and sends it parameters.

This `Page2` has an array with a binding to his template. If I do `pop()` and then enter otherwise to `Page2`, double the contents of the array because it seems to be not automatically cleaned when exiting.

Then I solved it by making an `array.lenght = 0` inside `ionViewWillLeave ()`.

This works fine if I navigate between `Page1` and `Page2`, since the array is emptied out of `Page2` and sent back from Page1 if I re-enter.

The problem with this is that I actually have a third Page, which is below `Page2`.

The scheme would be this:

```
Page 1 -------------------> Page 2 -----------------> Page 3
With parameters ------ With array----------------
```

When I navigate from `Page2` to `Page3`, `ionViewWillLeave()` is executed and the array is cleaned. Then when we go back (from `Page3` to `Page2`), the array is empty because obviously `Page3` does not return the contents of the vector as it does `Page1`. And so I have an empty `Page2` template.

For this same thing I would need an event to run only after pop, to clean the array only when `pop()` is made from `Page2`, and it will not run whenever it is going to quit page hint.

Thank's so much in advance!

Ivan.

Comment: Seems like there must be another way to fix this. Why are you pushing the data in the Page2, when you can just set the parameter array to the page2 array? That way items wouldn't be duplicated... Please add some code to the post so we can take a look at it and think how to avoid some ugly workarounds...